# In Flask, implementing google oauth, I get a psycopg2 error

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, google-oauth, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am experiencing an issue with google authentication with flask, I have implemented github oauth, that seems working great, but with google auth I am unable to add the authentication id, email, etc to the postgresql database and I am unable to query the data

`sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange) value "102734810329599019513" is out of range for type integer
LINE 1: ...th (user_id, provider, created_at, token) VALUES ('102734810...
^

[SQL: INSERT INTO flask_dance_oauth (user_id, provider, created_at, token) VALUES (%(user_id)s, %(provider)s, %(created_at)s, %(token)s) RETURNING flask_dance_oauth.id]
[parameters: {'user_id': '102734810329599019513', 'provider': 'google', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 24, 22, 33, 40, 232815), 'token': '{"access_token": "ya29.a0AfB_byDRRI73viV12s8KegSDmRuM2Y_AjdpFN7_x_-mNmBFj0HoO2Y_X8GS9MdheuAyLFpWC9tcIuOjNTCl_xCRb_tOqd4r_QLO_QcuwOOc68kh5IBz3Dzzhknsc ... (1185 characters truncated) ... ZHnFVTXZBv8nm0AvQrtIIkD2vyeNl49KagRJ94MIk7e5Kd7Afd2BiVnIn_1Km38CffgoZOXow8Uc3-s5vE_mcTnz3M0JVt1Wz0CoHnCyfKUVQNLLw", "expires_at": 1698190418.5201585}'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/9h9h)`

```
    __tablename__ = 'Users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)

    oauth_github  = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    oauth_google = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    api_token     = db.Column(db.String(100))
    api_token_ts  = db.Column(db.Integer)    

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for property, value in kwargs.items():
            # depending on whether value is an iterable or not, we must
            # unpack it's value (when **kwargs is request.form, some values
            # will be a 1-element list)
            if hasattr(value, '__iter__') and not isinstance(value, str):
                # the ,= unpack of a singleton fails PEP8 (travis flake8 test)
                value = value[0]

            if property == 'password':
                value = hash_pass(value)  # we need bytes here (not plain str)

            setattr(self, property, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.username)



@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(id):
    return Users.query.filter_by(id=id).first()


@login_manager.request_loader
def request_loader(request):
    username = request.form.get('username')
    user = Users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    return user if user else None

class OAuth(OAuthConsumerMixin, db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Users.id", ondelete="cascade"), nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship(Users)

@oauth_authorized.connect_via(google_blueprint)
def google_logged_in(blueprint, token):
    info = google.get('/oauth2/v1/userinfo')
    if info.ok:
        account_info = info.json()
        print(account_info, "infoooo1")
        user_id = account_info['id']

        query = Users.query.filter_by(oauth_google=user_id)
        try:
            user = query.one()
            login_user(user)
        except NoResultFound:
            oauth = OAuth(
                provider=blueprint.name,
                token=token,
                user_id=user_id
            )

            user = Users()
            user.username = 'google_' + account_info['given_name']
            user.email = account_info['email']
            user.oauth_google = user_id
    
            db.session.add_all([user, oauth])
            db.session.commit()
    
            login_user(user)
```

I tried changing id to a string but none of those worked, seems to be an error with interacting like the postgresql database cant seem to figure out the error help greatly appreciated

Comment: db.session.add(user)
solved by changing this

Comment: If you have solved the issue, post the solution as an answer or mark a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the value you are passing as a  `user_id` which is `102734810329599019513`, is out of the range of integer field in PostgreSQL. ([PostgreSQL Numeric Field Ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)).

To resolve the issue simply change the field type to `bigint` which in SqlAlchemy corresponds to [BigInteger](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.BigInteger)

Just replace

```
db.Integer
```

with

```
db.BigInteger
```

in both `user_id` and `id` of user table